# What does the e flag and special characters do in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, batch-processing, mysql-5.7

I am studying mysql from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/batch-mode.html . On second paragraph it says:

> If you are running mysql under Windows and have some special characters in the file that cause problems, you can do this:
>
> ```
> C:\> mysql -e "source batch-file"
> ```

- What are special characters? If I save a file in notepad, would there be automatic special characters saved in the file? How to know whether they are there or not? Are they hidden?
- What would the `-e` flag do? Where can I find its explanation in mysql documentation?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute

Comment: @e4c5 Yes I had sorted this out. Perhaps `source filepath` worked. But I don't remember exactly that now.

Comment: @e4c5 Yes your answer helped and I had upvoted it. But I still don't know what special characters are. I also don't know about history file. Once I clear things up I'll accept your answer :-)

Comment: Going through my old answers, I came across this one and was wondering what happened in the end.

Comment: @e4c5 Hi, (Sicilian Defence :-) I used to play Morra Gambit always) Actually I never neded to use `e flag` thereafter. Also I have been busy with front end projects. I never forget my posts on stackexchange. One day I will post my own answer to this question and accept your answer.

Comment: Glad to meet a fellow chess enthusiast

Answer (score 7):

`-e` is actually short for `--execute`, that's probably why you had trouble finding it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute

> Execute the statement and quit. The default output format is like that
>   produced with --batch. See Section 5.2.4, “Using Options on the
>   Command Line”, for some examples. With this option, mysql does not use
>   the history file.

A special charater is something that needs to be escaped in an SQL query. You will know when you run into them because mysql will produce errors.